# How to send ket from text file

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

my question is how i can use the code: variable.send_keys(text file)
i tried to do this but its not typing enything someone know what is wrog in my code?
i wnat to send word not with "" i want to send them from text file because the text going to change
to something else evry time

```
description = driver.find_element_by_id("product_short_description")
descriptionTypy = ActionChains(driver)
descriptionTypy.click(description)
descriptionTypy.perform()
f = open("descriptionTyper", 'r')
description.send_keys(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Try using this instead of just click

```
descriptionTypy.click(on_element=description)
```